# How to extract property values in string form, to loop over them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am practising with DOM manipulation, creating filters and combining them.

I have an array of objects similar to the one below, where there are properties (sorry if am not using the right tearms...) like `data.team` which can contain a string with several values separeted by commas.

Right now, checkbox filter only works when `data.cars` has only one value.
how could I handle them, so when I click on `Ferrari` i get all the players with that car, not only the one with that only car??

So far I've tried with `split` and looks promising...but
I cant find a way to make it work

```
let moreCars = []
justTeams = data[i].cars
justTeams.split(",");
moreCars.push(justTeams.split(","));
console.log(moreCars[0])
```

This is a reduced reproduction of my code. I hope it is not too confusing.

```js
let data = [{
    player: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    team: "Juventus",
    cars: "Bugatti, Ferrari, Aston Martin, Porsche",
  },
  {
    player: "Leo Messi",
    team: "Barcelona",
    cars: "Ferrari,Porsche, Audi",
  },
  {
    player: "Neymar",
    team: "Barcelona",
    cars: "Ferrari",
  },
  {
    player: "Mbappe",
    team: "PSG",
    cars: "Audi",
  },
]

function loadFunctions(data) {
  createTable(data);
  dropdown(data);
  setEventListeners(data)
}
loadFunctions(data)

// Create Table // 
function createTable(data) {
  const tBody = document.getElementById('table-data');
  tBody.innerHTML = ''

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');

    let tdName = document.createElement('td');
    let tdTeam = document.createElement('td');
    let tdCars = document.createElement('td');

    tdName.innerHTML = data[i].player;
    tdTeam.innerHTML = data[i].team;
    tdCars.innerHTML = data[i].cars;

    tBody.appendChild(row);

    row.appendChild(tdName);
    row.appendChild(tdTeam);
    row.appendChild(tdCars);
  }
}

// DROPDOWN

function dropdown(data) {
  let selectTeam = document.getElementById('team')
  var teamsArray = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    var allTeams = data[a].team;
    teamsArray.push(allTeams);
  }
  for (var a = 0; a < teamsArray.length; a++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.innerHTML = teamsArray[a];
    option.value = teamsArray[a];
    selectTeam.appendChild(option)
  }
}

function setEventListeners(data) {

  let playerTeam = document.getElementById('team').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    checkbox(data)
  });
  console.log(playerTeam)
  let checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=car]');
  Array.from(checkBoxes).forEach(function(oneCheckBox) {
    oneCheckBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      checkbox(data);
    })
  })
}

function checkbox(data) {
  let playerTeam = document.querySelector("#team").value;

  let checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=car]');
  let optionChecked = [];

  checkBoxes.forEach(function(oneCheckBox) {

    optionChecked =
      Array.from(checkBoxes) //convert to array to filter and map
      .filter(i => i.checked) // use array.filter to remove unchecked ones
      .map(i => i.value) // use array.map to extract checked values
    console.log(optionChecked)
  })
  filtering(data, optionChecked, playerTeam)
}

function filtering(data, optionChecked, playerTeam) {

  let filteredResults = [];
  if (optionChecked.length === 0 && playerTeam === 'all') {
    filteredResults = data
  } else if (optionChecked.length === 0 && playerTeam != 'all') {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].team == playerTeam) {
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  } else if (optionChecked.length != 0 && playerTeam === 'all') {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (optionChecked.includes(data[i].cars)) {
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (optionChecked.includes(data[i].cars) && data[i].team == playerTeam) {
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  createTable(filteredResults)
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h2 style="color: brown;">Football players and Fancy cars</h2>
  <!--checkboxes and dropdown -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <form class=form>
        <p>Filter by car</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Bugatti" id="bu">Bugatti</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Ferrari" id="fe">Ferrari</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Aston Martin" id="as">Aston Martin</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Porsche" id="pors">Porsche</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Audi" id="Au">Audi</label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Filter by team:</p>
      <select name="equipo" class="alltypes" id="team">
        <option value="all">All</option>

      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Table  -->
    <table style="width: 100%" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>equipo</th>
          <th>Cars</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-data">
        <!-- JS generated Table goes here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- end Table -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (optionChecked.includes(data[i].cars)) {
    filteredResults.push(data[i]);
}
```

Should change to:

```
if (data[i].cars.includes(optionChecked)) {
    filteredResults.push(data[i]);
}
```

You should check that if `optionChecked` exists in `data[i].cars` not vice-versa.
But I think there is something wrong in your algorithm, because how you want handle multiple selected checkboxes?!

---

**UPDATE**

You can check if `data[i].cars` has all checked options by this way:

```
if (optionChecked.length != 0 && playerTeam === 'all') {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      shouldAdd = true;
      optionChecked.forEach((option) => {
        if (!data[i].cars.includes(option)) {
          shouldAdd = false;
        }
      })
      if (shouldAdd) {
        filteredResults.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
```

Note

You have a typo (Bugatti), see below:

> `<label><input type="checkbox" name="car" value="Buggatti" id="bu">Bugatti</label>`

> {
> player: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
> team: "Juventus",
> cars: "Buggati, Ferrari, Aston Martin, Porsche",
> },

Comment: exactly. 
It should work in all the situations. If `data.cars` should contain just unique values, it would work the way it is. But it fails when there is more than one car as property.

Comment: thanks!! I adapted it also for the last `else` , and i think it works every time :)
However, I would much appreciate , if you had the time, to explain me a bit the logic behind your solution, so i can learn from it.

If not, never mind, your aweseome anyway  :)

Comment: nice job! At the first step (inside the 3rd or the last condition) we should check all items of `optionChecked` exist in the `data[i].cars`one by one, now consider we assume that car list has all items till we found an exception! if one by one check goes through all cases and list has them at the end we could add the data[i] to list, if one item does not exist we should not add data[i] into the list

Comment: good and easy explanation :)
Shukram one thousand times!! it is so nice to find users so willing to help in a nice way. 
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Well sorry i didn't understand your code at all, but this might be what can help you!

```
<body>
<style>* { font-family: sans-serif; }</style>
<div class="filter">
    <h1>Select Player</h1>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" onchange="filterData(this)" value="0"/>Cristiano Ronaldo</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" onchange="filterData(this)" value="1"/>Leo Messi</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" onchange="filterData(this)" value="2"/>Neymar</label>
    </div>

    <div id="result">
    </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var data = [{
    player: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    team: "Juventus",
    cars: "Buggati, Ferrari, Aston Martin, Porsche"
},
    {
    player: "Leo Messi",
    team: "Barcelona",
    cars: "Ferrari, Porsche, Audi",
},
    {
    player: "Neymar",
    team: "Barcelona",
    cars: "Ferrari"
}];

function filterData(t) {
    if (!t.checked) return;

    index = parseInt(t.value);
    result = document.getElementById("result");

    elem1 = document.createElement("h1")
    elem2 = document.createElement("h2")
    elem3 = document.createElement("h3")

    elem1.innerText = data[index].player;
    elem2.innerText = data[index].team;
    elem3.innerText = data[index].cars;
    result.innerHTML = '';
    result.appendChild(elem1);
    result.appendChild(elem2);
    result.appendChild(elem3);
}
```

Maybe this helps you!

Comment: may I ask you why or what you did not understood. Just to learn from my mistakes, or post a better question next time :)